# Select data going back from an amount of days specified in a sql table

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to modify my query to output only data that is in my sql table (ipaccounting), column (timeanddate) within the last "number" of days specified in another table (datapackages), column (thresholdtimespandays)

The data that is stored in `ipaccounting,timeanddate` looks like "2017-10-16 07:45:53" and the `datapackages,thresholdtimespandays` are just a solid number like "7" (last 7 days from now)

What do I need to add/change in my query?

My current query is:

```
SELECT ip_address
      ,SUM(upload_bytes) as upload_bytes
      ,SUM(download_bytes) as download_bytes
      ,sum(upload_bytes + download_bytes) as totalbytes
      ,package_id
      ,username
      ,networkaccess
      ,packagename
      ,speedlimit
      ,threshold
      ,throttlelimit
      ,datalimitamount
      ,datalimitrange
      ,thresholdtimespandays
FROM (
      (SELECT ipaccounting.src_address as ip_address
             ,SUM(ipaccounting.bytes) AS upload_bytes
             ,0 as download_bytes
             ,users.username
             ,users.networkaccess
             ,datapackages.package_id
             ,datapackages.packagename
             ,datapackages.speedlimit
             ,datapackages.threshold
             ,datapackages.throttlelimit
             ,datapackages.datalimitamount
             ,datapackages.datalimitrange
             , datapackages.thresholdtimespandays
      FROM ipaccounting
      join users on users.ipaddress = ipaccounting.src_address
      join datapackages on datapackages.package_id = users.datapackage
      WHERE dst_address NOT BETWEEN INET_NTOA('192.168.0.1') AND INET_NTOA('192.168.255.254')  
      GROUP BY src_address)

      UNION ALL 

      (SELECT ipaccounting.dst_address as ip_address
             ,0 AS upload_bytes
             ,SUM(ipaccounting.bytes) as download_bytes
             ,users.username
             ,users.networkaccess
             ,datapackages.package_id
             ,datapackages.packagename
             ,datapackages.speedlimit
             ,datapackages.threshold
             ,datapackages.throttlelimit
             ,datapackages.datalimitamount
             ,datapackages.datalimitrange
             ,datapackages.thresholdtimespandays
       FROM ipaccounting 
       join users on users.ipaddress = ipaccounting.dst_address
       join datapackages on datapackages.package_id = users.datapackage
       WHERE src_address NOT BETWEEN INET_NTOA('192.168.0.1') AND INET_NTOA('192.168.255.254')  
       GROUP BY dst_address)
        ) a 
GROUP BY ip_address 
ORDER BY INET_ATON(ip_address)
```

I am not sure how to take the current time and minus that with the amount of days specified in my database `datapackages,thresholdtimespandays`and then give out the data.

Thanks :)

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: At the risk of repeating myself...

Comment: Don't worry, I figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have played around and figured it out myself!

My updated query is:

```
SELECT ip_address
  ,SUM(upload_bytes) as upload_bytes
  ,SUM(download_bytes) as download_bytes
  ,sum(upload_bytes + download_bytes) as totalbytes
  ,package_id
  ,username
  ,networkaccess
  ,packagename
  ,speedlimit
  ,threshold
  ,throttlelimit
  ,datalimitamount
  ,accountingdays
FROM (
  (SELECT ipaccounting.src_address as ip_address
         ,SUM(ipaccounting.bytes) AS upload_bytes
         ,0 as download_bytes
         ,users.username
         ,users.networkaccess
         ,datapackages.package_id
         ,datapackages.packagename
         ,datapackages.speedlimit
         ,datapackages.threshold
         ,datapackages.throttlelimit
         ,datapackages.datalimitamount
         ,datapackages.accountingdays
  FROM ipaccounting
  join users on users.ipaddress = ipaccounting.src_address
  join datapackages on datapackages.package_id = users.datapackage
  WHERE dst_address NOT BETWEEN INET_NTOA('192.168.0.1') AND 
INET_NTOA('192.168.255.254')
  and timeanddate BETWEEN SUBDATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 
datapackages.accountingdays DAY) AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
  GROUP BY src_address)

  UNION ALL 

  (SELECT ipaccounting.dst_address as ip_address
         ,0 AS upload_bytes
         ,SUM(ipaccounting.bytes) as download_bytes
         ,users.username
         ,users.networkaccess
         ,datapackages.package_id
         ,datapackages.packagename
         ,datapackages.speedlimit
         ,datapackages.threshold
         ,datapackages.throttlelimit
         ,datapackages.datalimitamount
         ,datapackages.accountingdays
   FROM ipaccounting 
   join users on users.ipaddress = ipaccounting.dst_address
   join datapackages on datapackages.package_id = users.datapackage
   WHERE src_address NOT BETWEEN INET_NTOA('192.168.0.1') AND 
INET_NTOA('192.168.255.254') 
   and timeanddate BETWEEN SUBDATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 
datapackages.accountingdays DAY) AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
   GROUP BY dst_address)
    ) a 
GROUP BY ip_address 
ORDER BY INET_ATON(ip_address)
```

I have also made a few changes to my database as well such as `datapackage.thresholdtimespandays` to `datapackage.accountingdays` so my query will be a little different from my question.